# Interpolate variables into data attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

This is how I usually create a link with data.

```
= link_to 'link name', link_path, data: { day: '1' }
```

but now I need the "1" to be replaced with a rails variable like this.

```
= link_to 'link name', link_path, data: { day: '#{customer.info}' }
```

but It doesn't work and I'm not sure how to go about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are already in a Ruby context, just use the variable.

```
= link_to 'link name', link_path, data: { day: customer.info }
```

What your existing code is doing is passing a string with ruby code inside. The code will not be evaluated because wrapped by single quotes.

In order to use interpolation, you must use double quotes.

```
= link_to 'link name', link_path, data: { day: "#{customer.info}" }
```

However, as I mentioned at the begin of the answer, you don't need to interpolate the value since here.

Answer (score 3):

You can interpolate variables into strings created only with double quotes `"`:

```
= link_to 'link name', link_path, data: { day: "#{customer.info}" }
```

By the way, the following seems just enough:

```
= link_to 'link name', link_path, data: { day: customer.info }
```

Comment: You and Simone both answered the same thing, I wanted to set both as correct but since I can't I'll just give you an up-vote. Thank you for your time.